# Have user's touch engage w/ scrollview after gesture

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

Is there a way to have the user's touch re-engage with a UI element well after their finger made contact with the screen?

The feature I am trying to implement is one where the user will *only* be able to control the `UIScrollView` in the background once they have made a specific gesture (like a swipe), which would be recognized via a UIGestureRecognizer.

Any suggestions or ideas would be helpful!

Comment: You could have a transparent view on top of your controller's view that consumes all touch events until it's gesturerecognizer is activated, then it bubbles them to the next view.

Comment: Could you explain how one might "bubble" a user to another view?

Comment: If a view doesn't consume the touch, it moves on down the view hierarchy until a view consumes the touch.  That is commonly called "Bubbling."  So if you top view doesn't consume the touch event, your scrollview that is directly beneath it will.

Comment: Could I, in theory, have both the top view and the scrollview consume the touch, and have the scrollview only respond to the touch once the top view detects a gesture?

Comment: Consume means to take and not give to anything else.  By definition they could not both "consume" the event...

Comment: Good point. But what if instead, I used the UIGestureRecognizerDelegateProtocol method gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: to detect the touch on both views simultaneously?